# Passing variables via HTML into a PHP function

Tags: php, html, web

How would one pass a parameter from a PHP result into a HTML button then into another PHP function.

What I personally have is a table of records and next to the record is a link to another HTML page. The page will contain more detailed information of the record selected at first. E.g. Client then once clicked, that clients information.

This Function gets all the companies in a row along with a button (to  beside it in another column

```
function display_companies(){
    $conn = connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM company";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        echo "<table >
        <tr><th>Companies</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>$row[Name]</td>
        <td><a href='../Views/displayconnection.php'>Display Connection</a></td>
              </tr>";          
                                                }
}
```

Then I want the parament of the name to be passed down to this block of code

```
function display_company_connection($name){

    $conn = connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM companyconnection WHERE CompanyName='$name'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        echo "<table >
        <tr><th>Detail</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>$row[CompanyName]</td>
        <td>$row[Version]</td>
        <td>$row[methodOfConnection]</td>
        <td>$row[usesVPN]</td>
        <td>$row[ipAddress]</td>
        <td>$row[serverLoginUser]</td>
        <td>$row[serverPassword]</td>
        </tr>";
                                                }
}
```

both functions are in 1 file. the `main.php` file
`company.html` is what contains the company name and buttons and once a button is pressed it goes to `displayconnection.php` which will `include display_company_connection($name)` and display the table of information

Comment: Could you please edit your question and specify your files structure (which file in which directory) ?

Comment: This has been done below

Comment: I have your answer but since there are so many things that would deserve to be written in another way, could you post all your code (don't show your database credentials) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change the file extension from *.html* to *.php* i.e change `company.html` to `company.php`.

Second, on **company.php** page, you can append `$row['Name']` value to the URL like this:

```
echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
    <td><a href='../Views/displayconnection.php?name=" . urlencode($row['Name']) . "'>Display Connection</a></td>
</tr>";
```

And then on **displayconnection.php** page, get the URL parameter value using `$_GET` superglobal and simply pass this value to `display_company_connection()` function, like this:

```
// Get the URL parameter value
$name = $_GET['name'];

// Pass $name to display_company_connection() function
display_company_connection($name);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity is the ".  . " what makes a item appear in the URL? and then url encode calls the item

Comment: @T.Pilvelis That's why I didn't want to give an answer like that even if that's the good answer. There are many things in your code that need to be clarified.

Comment: @T.Pilvelis `../` means, with respect to the current directory, go one level up in the directory hierarchy. And I used `url_encode()` to encode the query part of the URL, more information is here in the doc, [http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)